# oidc-client CheckSessionIFrame fires properly one time, then fails ever interval thereafter

Tags: javascript, iframe, aurelia, identityserver4

This may not actually be an issue with Identity Server or the oidc-client, but I am having trouble pinning down the problem.  I am running this through System.js in an Aurelia application, so it's possible the issue originates from one of these external libraries.

In `CheckSessionIFrame.start(session_state)`, we have the following code:

```
this._timer = window.setInterval(() => {
  this._frame.contentWindow.postMessage(this._client_id + " " + this._session_state, this._frame_origin);
}, this._interval);
```

The first time the interval fires, there appear to be no problems.  The iFrame's contentWindow exists (as expected) and the postMessage method is called without issue.  Two seconds later, when the interval fires again, `this._frame.contentWindow` is undefined - so my best guess is the iFrame is dying somehow.  Again, this may not be an issue with oidc-client, but I'm looking for any helpful guidance on what could cause this iFrame to die (perhaps internally it could be dying on a script?) such as a missing necessary config value for oidc-client.

Answer (score 1):

For oidc-client to work with silent renew, you need to have your aurelia-app on an element that is not the body, so you can place elements within the body yet outside of your aurelia-app.

This allows you to put the IFrame outside of the aurelia-app, which prevents the Aurelia bootstrapper from eating it and lets oidc-client function independently of Aurelia.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, and a little memory refreshing on my part, I rephrase/clarify:

The session checker and the silent renew functions work independently of each other. You can silent renew before the session checker has started with a manual call. You can also start the session checker without doing any silent renew. They are just convenient to use together, but that's their only relationship.

I'm assuming you use the hybrid flow and have the standard session checker implementation with an RP and OP iframe, where the OP iframe is in a `check_session.html` page and the RP iframe is somewhere in your aurelia app. In one of my projects I have the RP iframe in the `index.html`, outside of the aurelia-app element so it works independently of aurelia. But I guess it doesn't necessarily have to be there.

The session checker starts when you set the `src` property of the RP iframe to the location of your **check_session.html** with the `session_state`, `check_session_iframe` and `client_id` after the hash.

The **check_session.html** page will respond to that by starting the periodic polling and post a message back to the `window` of your aurelia app if the state has changed.

From your aurelia app, you listen to that message and do the `signinSilent()` call if it indicates a changed state. And from the **silent_renew.html** page, you respond to that with `signinSilentCallback()`

All that being in place, it really doesn't matter when you start the session checker. Tuck it away in a feature somewhere and load that feature last.

The only two things you need to worry about during the startup of your application is:

- Check for `window.hash` starting with `#code` and call `signinRedirectCallback(code)` if it does
- If it does not, just call `signinSilent()` right away (that leaves you with the least amount of things to check)

And then after either of those have been done, do `getUser()` and check if it's null or if the `expired` property === true. If either of those is the case, do the `signinRedirect()`. If not, your user is authenticated and you can let the aurelia app do it's thing and start the session checker etc.

I would definitely **not** put the initial authentication checks on your index.html within the aurelia-app. Because if aurelia happens to finish loading before the oidc checks are done, the process will fail. You also probably want to store the user object (and UserManager) in some cache/service/other type of singleton class so you can easily interact with oidc from your aurelia application.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out what is actually causing the problem.  I am wondering if there might be another way I can solve it.  Do you know if it is possible to delay the setting up of silent-renew?  I need the oidc-client initialized to be able to tell me whether the user is logged in BEFORE initializing Aurelia (so I can redirect quicker), but the checksession functionality isn't needed right off the bat.

Comment: Do you have a separate `check_session.html` with the OP iframe, have the RP iframe in your aurelia main view, and a separate `silent_renew.html` with the `signinSilentCallback()`?